# Is there a game for Farore?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series, zelda-oracle-of-seasons, zelda-oracle-of-ages

My question comes from the "Oracle of [Ages/Seasons]" games, where the main "Damsel" is Nayru/Din respectively.

Now from the lore, Nayru and Din were the goddesses that created Hyrule. Nayru is the Goddess of Wisdom, and Din is the Goddess of Strength.

However, the third Goddess; Farore the Goddess of Courage is missing from this particular series.

So; my question is a bit of a two-parter.

1. Is there a game similar to these, where Farore is a main character in the games storyline, similar to Ages/Seasons?
2. Are Din and Nayru actually the Goddesses from the Lore, or are they just using the same names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no game in which Farore holds a role as important as Din or Nayru in the Oracle games. Well, kind of. She was meant to appear in [**Mystical Seed of Courage**](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Mystical_Seed_of_Courage) along with *Oracle of Ages* and *Oracle of Seasons*, but the game was cancelled due to the complexity of having to synchronize 3 games.

As a result of having her own game cancelled, [**Farore**](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Farore_(oracle)) has become a minor character in both *Oracle* games, and appears in *Minish Cap* along with her sisters, Din and Nayru.

---

As for the second question: No, the Oracles aren't the Goddesses, they're human.

However, they not only share their name with the Goddesses of legend, but also share their appearance, as seen in *Wind Waker*, where a statue of Din the Goddess can be found. They also happen to be sisters, same as the Goddesses.

This at least hints that the Oracles and the Goddesses may be related; perhaps they're incarnations of the Goddesses? Human descendants? Or maybe just 3 sisters whom the Goddesses have decided to share some of their powers with? Since it is never truly explained in the canon, we can only speculate.

Answer (score 4):

There [was supposed to be a third game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Oracle_of_Seasons_and_Oracle_of_Ages#Development) featuring Farore, but Capcom decided that it would be too complex to link three games together. Instead, Farore cameos in both Oracle games in the Hall of Secrets as the Oracle of Secrets, where she is responsible for allowing the player to enter passwords that link the two games together.

There has been no word from on high if the Oracles are in fact the Goddesses, but many surmise that they are the reincarnations of such.